# Designing a DFA to accept a string

Tags: computer-science, automata, finite-automata

[image]

I have created the following FA

[image]

Im i correct?

Comment: is that a... Euro symbol?

Comment: @DavidP Yep. Closest thing to an $\in$ on the keyboard I suppose.

Comment: @DavidP where.....?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Almost. But your DFA doesn't accept $00010$. In fact, if the DFA accepts $a0b1w$ where $a,b\in \{0,1\}$ and $w\in \{0,1\}^*$, then $\lvert w\rvert$ is a multiple of $4$. In fact the language of your DFA is $((0+1)0(0+1)1)^+$ i.e. $(.0.1)^+$ where "$.$" is "any symbol", i.e. $(0+1)$.

Fortunately, this is easily fixed: instead of transitioning from state $F$ to $B$ on any symbol, instead make the transitions $F\stackrel{0,1}\to F$. Once the machine reaches $F$, it never leaves (for any suffix $w$ of an input of the form $a0b1w$).

Comment: This was a question on last day's exam.Hope they will not see this .. :) or just ignore.How much % im i right?

Comment: Plus if you transition from F to F how does this FA accept long strings.Since F Leads to no other state..???

Comment: Noo, $F$ leads to *itself*: $F\stackrel{0,1}\to F$. Just because a DFA ends up in an accepting state while processing an input doesn't mean it *stops*! It consumes the entire input, and accepts it *iff* it ends up in an accepting state. With the change suggested, the machine accepts every $a0b1w$. The first four symbols put in in state $F$, and no matter what $w$ is, the machine stays in $F$; so the string is accepted.

Comment: Okay...my bad.But what % im i right.Will i get some points for this.....Just wondering

Comment: It's hard to quantify "percentage of falseness" of a proof :) What perentage you get really depends on the grader, the grader's mood, ... . Anywhere from 50% to, say, 75%.

Comment: I think there is this only 1 mistake you suggested.Hope i will get at-least something

Comment: Yes, the rest is correct. From another, more optimistic perspective, you got $12$ out of $14$ transitions right :) Good luck.

Comment: Thanks.... Been trying hard on this one.Was a failed exam,retook it :)